# Escape LIKE parameters containing wildcard characters like % (and _)

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

In [GORM documentation](https://gorm.io/docs/query.html#String-Conditions) there is an example how to use LIKE conditions:

```
// LIKE
db.Where("name LIKE ?", "%jin%").Find(&users)
// SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%jin%';
```

The problem that I have with this approach is that if `jin` is user input variable it can contain wildcard symbols like `%`. How can I escape such wildcard symbols?

For me these symbols must be used in the left part like:

```
db.Where("name LIKE %?%", "jin").Find(&users)
```

OR

```
db.Where("name LIKE '%' || ? || '%'", "jin").Find(&users)
```

and the ORM should escape automatically the parameter, but this is not how it behaves.

What is the right solution?

Comment: *"How can I escape such wildcard symbols?"* -- with the escape character, which by default is the backslash character. You can do the escaping in Go or in postgres. You can do it with regular expression's replace functionality, or you can do it by parsing the string yourself. The choice is yours. An example of doing it in postgres with regexp would be something like `'%' || regexp_replace($1, '(%|_)', '\\\1', 'g') || '%'`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to explicitly replace the wildcards:

```
db.Where("name LIKE '%' || replace(replace(?, '%', '\%), '_', '\_') || '%'", "jin").Find(&users)
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape explicitly.

```sql
db.Where("name like '%'||?||'%' escape '\'", userinput)
```

and escape wildcard symbols in the user input upfront before passing to `db.Where`. Backslashes in the user input shall be doubled too.

Unrelated but I would much prefer the regexp `~` and `~*` operators instead of `like`.

Comment: This is just changing how you escape, but escaping is still necessary

Comment: @Stefanov.sm `'%?%'` is a string literal which means the `?` is quite unlikely to be replaced by the provided argument.

Comment: @mkopriva Fair enough, it wouldn't.

Comment: @JulianPopov Well, someone has to do it in the end.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm But, how? you are just setting the escape symbol but not doing any escaping

Comment: I suggested to do that in the logic tier. Your regexp suggestion is better. You have forgotten the backslash itself though.